# how to return an observation value by indicate column name

Tags: r

I have a `df` as below. I want to write a `gas <- function(state): gas(AK)` will return AK's gas number 2.574121; `gas(CT)` will return the CT's gas number 0.8118408. What command will allow me to do that. Desperate for the answer, thank you!!

[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wDv2.png)

Comment: Try `df["gas", "CT"]` or `df["gas", "AK"]`

Comment: Thank you! Now I know how to write the function.